# Jenkins Windows Slave Disappears on restart

Tags: jenkins, master-slave

I have a Jenkins master setup which has 2 linux slaves and a windows slave. I have a configuration where all boxes are switched off in the night and restarted in the morning. The Jenkins master shows 2 linux nodes in the morning however it does not show windows slave (it just disappears and not even shown offline). The Jenkins version I am using : 2.73.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to swarm configuration which was resolved after putting together correct configuration files and enable on machine startup (to handle a situation if the machine goes down).